When logging in to Oracle Enterprise Manager as system on CDB In the Status section of the Database Home page, there is not CDB (n PDBs) link
For Access the Container Page for a CDB, Enter the URL for EM Express for CDB in my browser and log in as the SYS user (But i don't have a check for sysdba).
I log in
In the Status section of the Database Home page, I can't find the link to administer the cdb.
i tried this procedure in the same mode with user sys e system, but i have the same result.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i have installed oracle 19C desktop type. i'd like to connect to Oracle enterprise Manager Exspress as sysdba. But i don't have the check for sysdba. Because of this  problem in the box Status the link to administer the cdb doesn't appear. how could i administer CDB?
